# I can ping only some websites. At my wits end

Tags: ping, connection

I have a really strage phenomenon in one of our data centers.

I can ping facebook.com, yahoo.com, deb.nodesource.com and a few others (DNS resolution works fine).
But I can't ping google.com, archive.ubuntu.com and lots more. DNS works here, too.
I can also ping 1.1.1.1 (Cloudflare DNS) but not 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS).

Firewall rules look ok to me - there are no recent changes and it worked before. LAN hosts have an allow all rule anyway.
I am also connected to the DC via VPN, which works great, too. So connectivity wise I should be fine.

Help me out here guys, I don't know where to look anymore... How can I debug this any further?

edit:

I did a dig @1.1.1.1 for google.com:

root@dhcp01:[~]:  dig google.com @1.1.1.1

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52659
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1536
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     296 IN  A   216.58.209.142

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 24 14:44:09 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

pinging the returned IP has 100% packet loss.

I also did various traceroutes, here's the one to Google:

```
root@dhcp01:[~]:  traceroute 216.58.209.142
traceroute to 216.58.209.142 (216.58.209.142), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1 - 3 [removed because I'm paranoid]
 4  xe-5-1-1-150.cty-pe2.lla.se.ip.tdc.net (213.50.123.149)  1.604 ms  1.635 ms  1.656 ms
 5  ae0-0.kst-pe7.sto.se.ip.tdc.net (88.131.143.173)  12.171 ms  12.181 ms  12.158 ms
 6  hgd-core-1.bundle-ether41.tele2.net (130.244.200.78)  14.173 ms  13.449 ms  13.507 ms
 7  72.14.195.164 (72.14.195.164)  12.146 ms  12.045 ms  12.027 ms
 8  108.170.253.161 (108.170.253.161)  13.145 ms 108.170.253.177 (108.170.253.177)  16.112 ms  16.037 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

[image: The IP is pingable, but only from Sweden - where the datacenter is]

Comment: Hi, ping don't work, but that cause what problem ? try nslookup with 8.8.8.8 server to do a real test

Comment: yea, I did a dig google.de @1.1.1.1 which returns 216.58.209.142. This IP has 100% packet loss from the same host. Problem is, apt-get usw don't work. Most web sites are not accessible from there.

Comment: Use `traceroute` to determine if connectivity is lost inside your network or outside.

Comment: I also did a traceroute to various sites, I edit my question accordingly

Comment: The last IP `108.170.253.161` is owned by Google. May be anti DDOS service is working now on your or Google sides.